# Push Notification in Mobile Xamarin using Firebase

Tags: authentication, firebase, xamarin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new in xamarin. I need to implement a mobile app with push notification (maybe using Firebase) with user authentication. One user can send a notification to one or more than one user. So far I cannot find the right tutorial.

Would you help me find the way to implement a mobile app with push notification (maybe using Firebase)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first and second links (don't count the ad) in [Google Search Results](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=fcm+xamarin) looks like a good read. For the official docs for Firebase Cloud Messaging, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

Answer (score 1):

Hi flo you can start with [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) which can help you to get into working of FCM.
and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) you can get the topic messaging i.e. sending to multiple devices and at this [place](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience) you can see the steps which can be used for xamarin you just have to see the corresponding files in xamarin.